# How to check if my object is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object as follow:

```
this.student = {};
this.student.id = '';
this.student.name = '';
this.student.class = '';
this.student.percentage = '';
```

How do i check if my student object is empty or not?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **empty**?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a *very* active place. When you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can clarify things, such as Nikhil's question above. Everyone seems to have interpreted your question as being about a truly empty object (no properties), but looking at your question, I suspect that's not correct...

Answer (score 0):

To Check bject for empty try this

```
Object.keys(this.student).length === 0
```

Comment: An object can have non-enumerable properties.

Comment: I am getting following error :TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

Comment: @MeenakshiRathod - You will not get that error from the code above if it's used after the code in your question. Why not answer [the question you were asked half an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812197/how-to-check-if-my-object-is-empty-in-javascript#comment88629635_50812197)?